# Can fetch() do responseType=document?

Tags: xmlhttprequest, fetch-api

XHR's `responseType='document'` is awesome because it hands you back a DOM document that you can use querySelector, etc on:

```js
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', '/', true);
xhr.responseType = 'document';
xhr.onload = function(e) {
  var document = e.target.response;
  var h2headings = document.querySelectorAll('h2');
  // ...
};
```

Is this possible with the `fetch` method?

Answer (score 9):

It's not natively supported in `fetch` as the API is a purely network-layer API with no dependencies on being in a web browser ([see discussion](https://github.com/whatwg/fetch/issues/16)), but it's not too hard to pull off:

```js
fetch('/').then(res => res.text())
  .then(text => new DOMParser().parseFromString(text, 'text/html'))
  .then(document => {
    const h2headings = document.querySelectorAll('h2');
    // ...
  });
```

Comment: Is there a difference in doing it manually using a DOMParser vs the native XHR way?

Did XHR did it on a different thread say `HTMLParserThread` and doing it via `DOMParser` would do it on main UI thread or any other treadoff?

Comment: @prateekbh nope, these are equivalent. Same thread. Same semantics. Here's the impl of XHR's responseType document: https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/third_party/blink/renderer/core/xmlhttprequest/xml_http_request.cc?q=%22XMLHttpRequest::InitResponseDocument%22&g=0 .. The implementation of the two appears to be the same.

Comment: This assumes the response is an HTML document, where XHR is able to parse XML/SVG documents, solely based on the responseType header.