# res.text() is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, axios

I have a simple html string like `'<html><body><h1>hello world!!!!!</h1></body></html>'`. I want to convert it to text but I am getting error like `.text is not a function`

My main purpose is to convert url into html. This is my code

```
      axios({
            method: 'get',
            url: url,
            headers:{
                "Content-Type":"text/html"
            },
        }).then(async (res) => {     
                const html = await res.data.text();
                console.log('html:', html);
        }).catch((e) => {
            console.log('e: ', e);
        })
```

I consoled `res.data` and I got html string but I am not able to convert it to text.
I tried to put hardcoded html string to `.text()` but I am getting the same error that .text is not a function

Is there .text() method ? Why am I getting this error ?
Does anybody have other solution ?

Comment: If `res.data` is the string.. then just use that string? You already have the string. What would be the purpose of trying to chain on another `.text()`? (You'd use `.then(res => res.text())` when using fetch, but not here)

Comment: I have asked question on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73787816/how-to-convert-url-into-html-in-javascript/73788052#73788052 can you please refer that to know what exactly I am gonna do

Comment: My comment still stands... that uses fetch, not axios

Comment: Your GET request has no content and therefore does not require a content-type header. What makes you think a plain [String](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#instance_methods) would have a `text()` method? All you need is `const html = res.data;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you specify the `responseType` in your request options, you can directly receive an HTML document without having to worry about parsing it

```js
// just an example HTML page
const url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/index.html";

axios.get(url, { responseType: "document" }).then(({ data }) => {
  // data is an HTML document
  const title = data.querySelector("h1").textContent;
  console.log("title:", title);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.27.2/axios.min.js" integrity="sha512-odNmoc1XJy5x1TMVMdC7EMs3IVdItLPlCeL5vSUPN2llYKMJ2eByTTAIiiuqLg+GdNr9hF6z81p27DArRFKT7A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

This is possible because Axios (when run in the browser) uses [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) which automatically supports rich (parsed) [response](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/response) types.

The [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) which is used in the post you linked to unfortunately [does not support such a convenience](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45512103/283366) and the response must be parsed.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking to get out of it only `hello world!!!!!`, then use DOMParser to turn it into a document, then get the document's text content.

```
axios(url)
  .then((res) => {     
    const htmlText = res.data;
    const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(htmlText, 'text/html');
    const plainTextContent = doc.body.textContent.trim();
    // use plainTextContent
  }).catch((e) => {
    console.log('e: ', e);
  });
```